# How does custom loss function in pyTorch work?

Tags: pytorch, loss-function, autograd

I see pytorch provides support to write custom loss functions. Consider following hinge loss.

```
class MarginRankingLossExp(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(MarginRankingLossExp, self).__init__( )

    def forward(self,input1,input2,target):
        # loss_without_reduction = max(0, −target * (input1 − input2) + margin)
        neg_target = -target
        input_diff = input2-input1
        mul_target_input = neg_target*input_diff
        add_margin = mul_target_input
        zeros=torch.zeros_like(add_margin)
        loss = torch.max(add_margin, zeros)
        return loss.mean()
```

This has only forward and constructor function defined. How does pytorch calculate gradient for custom functions? Does it differentiate it somehow?
Also,  This function is non differentiable at y=margin but it didn't throw any error.

Comment: Can you link the code snippets in question? As it stands, this question is too vague to provide a specific answer.

Comment: Added please recheck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function will be differentiable by PyTorch's autograd as long as all the operators used in your function's logic are differentiable. That is, as long as you use `torch.Tensor` and built-in `torch` operators that implement a backward function, your custom function will be differentiable out of the box.

In a few words, on inference, a computational graph will be constructed on the fly. That is, for every operation you make, the tensors necessary to compute the gradients will be matched for a later backward pass. Assuming that you use only differentiable operators (*i.e.* most operators are mathematically differentiable and as such PyTorch provides the backward functionality for them). You will be able to perform backpropagation on the graph: from the end of it from the *loss term*, up to its leaves on *parameters* and *inputs*.

A very easy way to tell if your function is differentiable by Autograd is to infer its output with inputs which require gradient computation. Then check for a `grad_fn` callback on the output:

```
>>> x1 = torch.rand(1,10,2,2, requires_grad=True)
>>> x2 = torch.rand(1,10,2,2, requires_grad=True)
>>> y = torch.rand(1,10,2,2)
```

Here we can check with:

```
>>> MarginRankingLossExp()(x1, x2, y)
tensor(0.1045, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
```

Where you notice `MeanBackward0` which refers to [`torch.Tensor.mean`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mean.html), being the very last operator applied by `MarginRankingLossExp.forward`.